# how get directory last modify date = textboxdate and get file in this directory c#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, directory

I have so many directories and these directories has so many files, I want get directory last modify date if directory **Modify date <= textbox date** get files and get number = txtnumber get filedata how can I do this...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"E:\Voip Caller Record\890001";
    var allfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);       
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not in the C# field, but generally the more effort you show in your questions the more you will get help. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the directory path to the instance of the `DirectoryInfo` and use the [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) `class`, `LastWriteTime` property to figure out when the directory was last written to (modified):

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("myDirPath");
if (info.LastWriteTime > someDate){
    var allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    //do something on allfiles
}
```

If it was last written after certain time, then get all the files in that directory by what you have shown and you could proceed as you want.

**Edit:**

If you need sub-directories instead of files, you could use `Directory.GetDirectories()` instead. And to get the directory last write time, simply do the same thing as above:

```
var alldirs = Directory.GetDirectories("myRootPath")
    .Select(x => new DirectoryInfo(x));
foreach (var dir in alldirs) {
    if (dir.LastWriteTime > someDateTime) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i want get sub directories last-modify datetime

Comment: @AdeelKhan did you look at the link I posted? It contains some fields which might be of your interest. The last modify and the last write should be the same thing. If it is not, please check the MSDN link.

Comment: yes dear... i check your link but i want sub directories last modify date-time also.. result show only directoryname

Comment: @AdeelKhan what do you mean by shows "only directoryname"? the `DirectoryInfo` has every info a directory should have, including the `LastWriteTime`. How do you check that the info only contains `directoryname`?

Comment: allfiles returns only file name i want directories last modify datetime also

Comment: You read my answer wrongly.... the point of my answer is *not* to use the `allfiles` (this is what you put, I merely copy it) but to use `DirectoryInfo`. That is to say, as long as you put a correct directory path you want to read the info from, you could get its `DirectoryInfo` very easily. If you want to get sub-directory from a directory, you should use `Directory.GetDirectories()` instead of `Directory.GetFiles()` and then pass each `string` in the obtained directory to the `DirectoryInfo` to get its `LastWriteTime`

Comment: @AdeelKhan great! Try it out! ;)

Comment: Thanks for reply :)

Comment: @AdeelKhan no problem, hope that helps! :) again, check out `DirectoryInfo` and also `Directory`